# how to set up a timer in a C# windows windows service

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, timer, windows-services

```
System.Timers.Timer scheduleTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
DateTime dtPrevDate = new DateTime();

    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        scheduleTimer.Enabled = true;
        int timerInterval = //number of seconds to the next 7th day of either current or next month;

        scheduleTimer.Interval = timerInterval
        scheduleTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(scheduleTimer_Elapsed);  
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        this.scheduleTimer.Start();
        dtPrevDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
        Logger.CreateLog("Service started");
    }
```

In the sample code above in my Windows service, how can i get the number of seconds to the next 7th day of either current or next month irrespective of whether the service was stopped, restarted or the server was rebooted?.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this utility function to get the `DateTime` that corresponds to the next `n`th day of either this or the following month.

```
private DateTime GetNthDay(int n)
{
    DateTime today  = DateTime.Today;
    DateTime nthDay = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, n);

    if ( nthDay <= today )
    {
        nthDay = nthDay.AddMonths(1);
    }

    return nthDay;
}
```

Using that, the rest is just basic math.

```
DateTime dtPrevDate    = DateTime.Now;
DateTime dtNextDate    = GetNthDay(7);
Double secondsTo7thDay = (dtNextDate - dtPrevDate).TotalSeconds;
```

Comment: if secondsTo7thDay is 63529747200.0 i get the following exception "Number must be either non-negative and less than or equal to Int32.MaxValue or -1.
Parameter name: dueTime" when setting the timers interval. What is the maximum value accepted for parameter dueTime?

Comment: I was not aware of that limitation. The max value of an integer is `2,147,483,647`. Perhaps a better solution is to set the interval to 1 hour, then check the current date and time in the `Elapsed` event.